# Stratus form for SharePoint. compare inputs after clicking Submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, sharepoint

I got this great form for SharePoint from Stratus form to implement it on SharePoint 2013. I got it working, but would like to add extra validation and it does not recognize or something else is not working, because when I click submit, the form submits even without matching input. Following is the code snippet. I am not sure how to add proper validation to input and sum.

```js
function CompareInputhpurs(){
   var inputTotalHours = document.getElementById("totalHours").value;
   var sumTotalhours = document.getElementById('Total');

   var comfirm = false;
   if(inputTotalHours===sumTotalhours){
 comfirm=true;
   } else {
 alert("Total hours worked does not match.Please input correct total hours.");
 comfirm =false;
   }
}
  
function SubmitForm(){
    
 //When the form is submitted store it to the specified list
 //also pass as in the x and y offset of error messages for elements
 //this allows you to change their location in reference to the form field
 $("#timesheetDiv").StratusFormsSubmit({
     listName: "DailySummary",
     errorOffsetTop: 0,
     errorOffsetLeft: 5,
     completefunc: function(id) { 
     CompareInputhpurs();
     alert("Save was successful. ID = " + id);
    //window.location = window.location.pathname + "?formID=" + id; 
     }  
  });
}
```

```html
<td>          
   <label class="thisLabel" for="time" >Total hours worked:</label>
   <input listFieldName="TotalHours" id="totalHours" class="inputClassSmall" validate="validNumber"/>        
</td>      
<div class="rTableRow">
   <div class="rTableCell"></div>
   <div class="rTableCell"></div>
   <div class="rTableCell"><label id="sumHours" class="thisLabel">Total hrs:</label><p id="Total"></p></div> 
</div> 
<input class="buttonClass" type="button" onclick="SubmitForm();" value="Add/Update Time Entry" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call CompareInputhpurs before StratusFormsSubmit if you want to do client side validation.

```
function SubmitForm(){
 CompareInputhpurs();               
 //When the form is submitted store it to the specified list
 //also pass as in the x and y offset of error messages for elements
 //this allows you to change their location in reference to the form field
 $("#timesheetDiv").StratusFormsSubmit({
     listName: "DailySummary",
     errorOffsetTop: 0,
     errorOffsetLeft: 5,
     completefunc: function(id) {       
        alert("Save was successful. ID = " + id);
       //window.location = window.location.pathname + "?formID=" + id; 
     }      
  });
}
```

Comment: yea i tried that, but it did not work. Is it because completefunc: is defined also in different javascript file